# How to print angular brackets in XML using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-v5.1

I want to print the angular brackets(<,>) in powershell, but it is printing to > and < instead respectively. Is there any way I can print those symbols.

I have used \ to overcome the bracket's escape properties and also single inverted commas but the result remains same.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Desktop\new.xml)
$xml.Deploy.app="$<abc\bc>"
$xml.Save("C:\Users\Desktop\new.xml")
```

I expected output to be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<Deploy>
  <app><abc\bc></app>
</Deploy>
```

but it printing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Deploy>
  <app>&lt;abc\bc&gt;</app>
</Deploy>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try creating a new node (as a subnode of `$xml.Deploy.app`) with the oddball name `abc\ab`.

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully explain better why some characters in XML are converted into their entity format. Also, it shows you CAN have characters like `<` and `>` unchanged in XML, but only if you insert them as a `CDATA` section.

Answer (score 2):

XML needs 5 characters to be replaced, because they have special meaning in XML. These characters are `<>&'"`
Here, you can not simply prepend these characters with some escape character like the backslash, instead they need to be converted into named or numbered [entities](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/bc4j/developing_bc_projects/obcCustomXml.htm).

As you have noticed, this conversion happens automatically in `[xml]`, but there are also a number of ways to do that manually if needed:

```
$str = "$<abc\bc>"
```

**1)** Using the String `.Replace()` method:

```
$str.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace('"', "&quot;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;")
```

**2)** Using .Net System.Security:

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
 [System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($str)
```

**3)** Using System.Xml.XmlDocument:

```
[xml]$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$node = $doc.CreateElement("root")
$node.InnerText = $str
$node.InnerXml
```

**4)** Using Regex:

```
$str -ireplace '&#34;|&#x(?:00)?22;|"', '&quot;' `
     -ireplace "&#39;|&#x(?:00)?27;|'", '&apos;' `
     -ireplace '&#60;|&#x(?:00)?3C;|<', '&lt;'   `
     -ireplace '&#62;|&#x(?:00)?3E;|>', '&gt;'   `
     -ireplace '&#38;|&#x(?:00)?26;|&(?!(?:[a-z]+|#[0-9]+|#x[0-9a-f]+);)', '&amp;'
```

All of the above will convert the XML special characters into entities, so the result will look like this:

> `$&lt;abc\bc&gt;`

---

If you absolutely don't want the XML special characters  to be converted into entities, then there is AFAIK only the option to set the value as a [CDATA section](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect), which will wrap your string inside `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`].
To use that in your example, change the line `$xml.Deploy.app="$<abc\bc>"` into this:

```
$xml['Deploy']['app'].AppendChild($xml.CreateCDataSection("$<abc\bc>")) | Out-Null
```

Now it will print:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <Deploy>
>   <app><![CDATA[$<abc\bc>]]></app>
> </Deploy>
> ```

To read back this CDATA value as string, you can do either `$value = $xml.Deploy.app.InnerText` or `$value = $xml.Deploy.app.'#cdata-section'`

Hope that explains

Comment: This happens automatically when you work with it as `[xml]` in PowerShell and save it that way. This is the opposite of what the user wants.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician It is explaining why the characters are converted in XML and that what the OP expects is not possible in XML.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You're right, the explaining part could have been a lot better. I have reworded my answer.

Comment: Excellent update! I've upvoted, and encourage the OP to accept this answer to help future searchers, and to give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 0):

This is just how XML works. The less than and greater than characters are reserved/special characters. When a value includes them it will convert them to their escaped forms `&lt;` and `&gt;`. What you expect to be output is invalid XML.

Comment: So how can I get <> in xml files?

Comment: You don't in the XML document that is saved to drive. Any XML parser will convert `&lt;` into `<` when it reads the XML file in, the same as any reserved character like that. You can test that by loading your saved XML file with the `&lt;` and what not in it, and then looking at the node's value.